# CELL Calculation with dynamic mdx expression

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap-cube

I've been trying for a while to create a (little bit complicated?) cell calculation where I need to use a dynamic formula but is not working. At the end I'm obtaining the mdx expression as the cell value, which is wrong. Here is my expression:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
---SET With 2 elements(Sales Fcst(20131223), Sales Fcst(2014))
WITH SET [CategoryFcst] AS 
FILTER([Category].[Category].children, InStr([Category].[Category].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION,"Sales Fcst") > 0 )


CELL CALCULATION SalesPlanAch FOR 
                 '([Category].[Category].[Sales Plan Att%], [Measures].[Amount])'   
                   AS 
                   '(StrToMember("' + [CategoryFcst].item(0).UNIQUENAME + '"),[Measures].[Amount] )'


--The formula expression result is: (StrToMember("[Category].[Category].&[29]"),[Measures].[Amount] )



SELECT [Time].[Calendar Time].[Quarter].members on columns,
[Category].[Category].children on rows

from [AllData]
WHERE ([Measures].[Amount])

-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If I put directly '`(StrToMember("[Category].[Category].&[29]"),[Measures].[Amount])`' as the cell calculation formula it will work, but I need to calculate that dynamically.

Also, if I put '`(StrToMember("' + '[Category].[Category].&[29]' + '"),[Measures].[Amount] )`' doesn't work. It sets that string as the cell value.

That is not the real cell calculation but the part that is causing me problems.
I'd appreciate any advice/answers.

Best regards,
Daniel

Comment: I've seen this kind of thing before and it might be related to the time the set is created. Can you replace the [CategoryFcst] in the calculation with the set definition? It might not be optimal but perhaps you can optimise it afterwards? Perhaps you can create a hierarchy to categorise those members rather than looking them up from the caption?

Comment: Hi Preet. Thanks for your answer. If I replace the [CategoryFcst] for the set definition I get an empty string and the result of the mdx expression is:(StrToMember(""),[Measures].[Amount] ). I need to look the members for the caption because the will be changing, so I cannot put something like this directly: [Catgeory].[Catgeory].[Sales Fcst(20140124)].

Comment: Would `'(StrToMember([CategoryFcst].item(0).UNIQUENAME),[Measures].[Amount] )'` give what you want?

Comment: Hi Frank. Thanks a lot. Yes, it does what I want. Do you have a logical explanation for that?

Comment: I explained the background in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
'(StrToMember([CategoryFcst].item(0).UNIQUENAME),[Measures].[Amount] )'
```

As far as I understand, the necessity of quotes around this expression is due to the history of Analysis Services [as described here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/mosha/archive/2005/04/02/to-quote-or-not-to-quote-in-expressions-of-mdx-calculations.aspx). And, as described in the same article, in version 2005 of Analysis Services, this was changed for member and set definitions in the `WITH` clause, but apparently not for the rarely used cell calculations. Hence, the quotes here are not something that encloses a string, but more or less a syntax requirement to enclose the expression.

I am actually not sure how you would use single quotes within this expression. But you can use double or single quotes in MDX expressions to enclose strings. Thus you will rarely come across the necessity to absolutely need single quotes in this type of expressions.